# Deploying yii2 in a subdirectory

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I deployed yii2 on a subdirectory. I am encountering problems on the redirection. On my localhost, i worked my project not in a subdirectory, so I am not having any problems. But when I deployed it on our live server and put the project in a subdirectory, I am having problems.

My problem is that when I visit the homepage of my site I am being redirected to the root of the website.

Here's an example:
Main site: http://example.com/

Yii2 Site: http://example.com/myproject/

When I try to go to http://example.com/myproject/, I am expected to be redirected at http://example.com/myproject/login, instead I am redirected to http://example.com/login.

I already changed my .htaccess into this one

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) system/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But i think this one is wrong though...

I also have this one on my web.php

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'defaultRoute' => 'site/login',
     //... other codes here...
```

As you can see i have a `defaultRoute` to be `site/login` but it seems i keep on redirecting on the `/login`, which is not in a subfolder link.

Any help how to set up yii2 in a subdirectory

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The UrlManager doesn't know that the app is not in the webserver's root directory.  Try setting your `$config['components']['urlManager']['baseUrl']` to your project's path:

```
// in web.php
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    //... other codes here...
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',        
            'baseUrl' => 'myproject',
        ]
    ]
]
```

BTW, you could shorten your `basePath` definition to

```
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
```

which should return the same directory with less (and IMHO cleaner) code.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the **RewriteBase** param of your `.htaccess` file by setting the path to your project folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /myproject

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
# RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) system/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `RewriteBase` be just `/myproject`?  Good point though!

Comment: Yes you're right, didn't notice the **system** folder included in the **RewriteRule**, Thanks @tarleb

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, modifying the `.htaccess` has strange effect,
**urlManager.baseUrl** config fixes url creations and roots,
**assetManager.baseUrl** config fixes script/styles path

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/myproject/',
    ...
    ],
    'assetManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => '@web/myproject/assets',
    ],
...
]
```